# Pull values from Firebase database and render in a React-Native-Chart-Kit

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-chart-kit

I am trying to pull down values from my Firebase realtime database and store them in the data section of a basic react-native-chart-kit. I am able to pull down the values but every time I try to insert the data into the data parameter of the chart, I get an error.

I have tried setting the data parameter to equal my array of values, I have also tried to just pass in one value at a time (as seen by the variable 'single') but each time I get an error.

[image: I get the following error for the code shown in the question]

This is the error I get for the code shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
componentDidMount() {
    itemsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let items = Object.values(data);
      this.setState({ items: items });

      var i = 0;
      var total = [];
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      {
        parseInt(items[i].name)
        total[i] = ''
        total[i] += items[i].name
      }

      this.setState({total})

      return total;
    });
  }

  render() {

    array = []
    array = this.state.total
    single = array[0]

    console.log(single)

    return (

      <React.Fragment>
      <View>

    <Text>Bezier Line Chart + {this.state.total}</Text>
  <LineChart
    data={{
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: this.state.total,
        },
      ],
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. To get rid of this error, I set the state to 0 for each data from firebase,
eg:

```
    class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            total: 0,
            isLoading: false,
        };
    };
```